# Previews of links on the edit screen are not always accurate

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, broken-link

The below link is only partially link-ified, but when you open up the edit screen the preview shows it full link-ified. I'm guessing it might be thrown off by the `$` or something?

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Answer (score 1):

If you use the proper markdown (insert a link using the toolbar) it shouldn't be an issue:

[link to documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

**Bare Url (enclosed in angle brackets):**

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Advice from [SO Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#bare-urls): (**emphasis mine**)

> We have modified our Markdown parser to support "naked" URLs (in most
>   but not all cases -- beware of **unusual characters** in your URLs); they
>   will be converted to links automatically:
>
> I often visit http://example.com.
>
> Force URLs by enclosing them in angle brackets:
>
> Have you seen <http://example.com>?
>
> URLs can be relative or full.

**Related:**

[markdown link parsing bug for urls with underscore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189749/markdown-link-parsing-bug-for-urls-with-underscore)

Comment: Agreed, but I saw another user doing this, and they didn't do that.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg it's a quick edit to fix that if you see it. adding a comment to notify the user of the fix would probably be useful too.

Comment: I think the problem is not the link in itself, who created it or how it was created, but the preview being incorrect: you (or at least I) would expect the result to be the same as in the preview. If the URL is correctly linked in the preview, but not in the final result, that's a bug

Comment: @Tanner Agreed for the cases I catch, but it would be better if we fix the bug so that isn't necessary. Moreover, I've never seen this markdown editing help and I doubt many other users have either, so the ideal solution would be to fix the bug.